# Why do Windows file transfers severely drop in performance after the initial period?

Tags: windows, ssd, performance, file-transfer

I have a Windows 10 machine with two SSDs. Sometimes, I'm able to get consistent 1GB/s file transfers between them for hundreds of GBs. Sometimes, after the initial high speed transfer, it drops like a rock to almost nothing at all. I have no other activity on this computer. If I run Linux instead, I *always* get 1GB/s. How do I go about root causing and resolving this?

[image]

Comment: Are you transferring from SSD to SSD or SSD to Google online? There can be many factors, if you're transferring online, are you using wireless, Google may have many people online using they're service all at once. It could be buffers, etc.

Comment: (1) "I have no other activity on this computer" Windows have a lot of background operation, you need to to be sure nothing else is using the SSD. (2) You have to be sure all data transfered is large file, not a lot of small files (3) With SSD you can never be sure what the bandwith should be and what is happening inside. With HDD you can be sure continiously allocated large file can be transfered with 100-200MB/s

Comment: @vssher As I said, "file transfers between them", referring to the two SSDs.

Comment: @jw_ I transfer a 50GB one day, I get 1GB/s. I transfer the same 50GB another day, I get 90MB/s. I look in the Task Manager for disk activity and I see nothing else. If I restarted the file transfer, I get the same high speed initial throughput, then a drop. I believe I've addressed all the possibilities you raised. What else?

Comment: @puritii If you really want to see what is happening while all this is going on try this tool "Process Monitor" https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon you can even see what is going on while your computer boots up, a very handy tool.

Comment: (4) You can try HDD to see whether it is the same, like 100MB/s for one day and 10MB/s for another day (5) Your high start low later may means that's not drive IO speed but RAM buffer speed, Windows can use GBs of RAM to buffer the transfered data until the buffer is full, the bottle neck is the write not the read(6) SSD just always disappoint you.

Comment: Use HDD and RAM where possible. SSD for read only data like OS/Game, and load that is too slow on HDD like database write. I even put pagefile to HDD (with oversized RAM)